# Saving uploaded image file in public dir not working in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, image-uploading

I have created a designated location to store all the uploaded images in public dir like this:

[image]

and I have the default `config/filesystem.php` for public driver like this:

```
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Within my repository, I am trying to save the uploaded image like this:

```
    // ... snipped        

    if (array_key_exists('logo', $validated)) {
        $logoPath = $validated['logo']->store(
            'uploads/logos',
            'public'
        );
        $company->logo = url($logoPath);
    }

    $company->save();
```

In the database, I can see the value of `logo` field for the company record like this: `http://my-app.local/uploads/logos/3hlsAhnnIPjd4zhdpfhvKw4tqDkpcCz23NczwhVM.png`

However, the `public/uploads/logos` dir is empty. Any idea what might be wrong here? Am I supposed to use the `->move()` method on the `UploadedFile` instead of `->store()`?

Comment: Is it maybe in the `storage` folder (`storage/app/public` by any chance)?

Comment: ah! you're right `'root' => storage_path('app/public'),` I think i need to update this path. Let me check.

Comment: Yup, it's been a minute since I worked with file upload. But `storage_path()` helper will generate the path to the storage folder. You probably just want to change that to something like `public_path('uploads')`. Or create a symlink from storage folder to public folder

Comment: Yea, this was the problem, i didn't pay enough attention to the filesystem definition. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alternative method for uploading images in your public directory.

```
$request->validate([
    'logo' => 'image|required',
]);

if($request->hasFile('logo')){
   $company->logo = $request->image->move('uploads/logo', $request->logo->hashName());
}
$company->save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, yes, it was your mistake, but not the one you just found. By default laravel local storage points to `storage/app/public` directory, because laravel wants you to act professionally and store all uploaded files in storage, not in some kind of public directory. But then you would ask - how on earth user should access non-public storage directly? And there is a caught - `php artisan storage:link` command. It creates symbolic link from public directory to storage directory (`storage/app/public` -> `public/storage`). This is mostly because of deployments and version management.